# MySQL SQL syntax gives column error

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I run the following syntax in mySQL:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@4f2f19fd: INSERT INTO Matches_2016_Qualification (Additional_information, Team_number, Points, Auton, Match_number) VALUES (NONE, 4602, 100, 0, 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NONE' in 'field list'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
at me.whereisthemonkey.ScoutingInformation.GUI.Matches.addMatch(Matches.java:236)
at me.whereisthemonkey.ScoutingInformation.GUI.MainGUI$1.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:73)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

That makes no sense because NONE is not even a column... Could I have a corrupted database? 
Do I need to declare the NONE as  \"NONE\" or as an other type?

Thank you for any help,
Lucas

Comment: Probably you have concatenated sql query. You should use parameter binding, and `NONE` should be `'NONE'`.

Comment: If you want to insert the string value "NONE", then yes you need to wrap it in quotes: `'NONE'`

Comment: Please post code you use to generate this query.

Answer (score 5):

`NONE` doesn't mean anything in MySQL.  The error message is simply saying "I don't recognize "NONE", so I think it is a column name and it is not".

Perhaps you mean one of the following:

```
VALUES ('NONE', 4602, 100, 0, 1)
VALUES (NULL, 4602, 100, 0, 1)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 4602, 100, 0, 1)
```

The first inserts the string `'NONE'` into the field; the second a `NULL` value and the third inserts the default value (if none is defined, then `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

your error: Unknown column 'NONE' in 'field list'

put this code in variable e.g.

Str = INSERT INTO Matches_2016_Qualification (Additional_information, Team_number, Points, Auton, Match_number) VALUES (NONE, 4602, 100, 0, 1)

then run to your mysql command line and give us the result.

what is your NONE data type?